# Directory size increased after compaction using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, file-format, data-compaction

I wrote a file compactor using pyspark.
The way that it works is by reading all the content of a directory into a spark dataframe and then performing a repartition action in order to reduce the number of files.
The number of desired files is calculated by: directory_size / wanted_file_size.

The issue I'm facing is that the size of directory after compaction is bigger then the size of directory before compaction.

for example:
Directory size before compaction is 68gb with 1431 files. after compaction the file count is 145 and the directory size is 76gb.
all files in this example are parquet and compressed with snappy before the compaction sequence and after.

can someone please help me understand why does the directory size is changing and how can i fix this??

Comment: Try the same thing but with simple csv files. If it works with csv files, it means that the operation you are trying to do is not working well with parquet which already compresses the files (columnar format)

Comment: do you mean that ill do the same but with a different file format?
the read operation in spark receives format to read so it'll be the same but just the format will change...

Comment: Yes. exactly. The same data in CSV (raw text) and parquet should not have the same size at the end. But in CSV, the same amount of data, in 1 file or 10 files shoulds be same size. Maybe, in parquet, reducing the number of files could increase the weight of the final files.

Comment: interesting, ill give it a try and look into it, just to make sure that the data is not compromised

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with your configuration, it's not ditributed enough. try to increase the number of workers and it'll figure out your issue. this is a classic issue with data skew

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).