# Data in hive table is changed after running a compaction in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hive, data-compaction

Following previously asked question [adding link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76618136/directory-size-increased-after-compaction-using-pyspark).

in short:
I wrote a file compactor in spark, the way that it works is by reading all files under a directory into a dataframe, performing coalesce over the dataframe (by the number of wanted files), writing them back into their directory and  then compressing them into snappy.

The problem I have:
The directories I'm compacting are actually partitions under a table in Apache hive, after rewriting back the files into their directory and performing a basic select query over the partition in hive it seems that the data is being altered, for example:

This table:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| null | 1 |

Turns into:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 1 | null |

can someone please help me understand why does the data is being altered and how can i fix it?

Comment: `coalesce` by itself does not change the schema of a dataframe, so your working assumption should be that something else is changing it. Can you do a `df_read.printSchema()` right after you read the data, and then `df_write.printSchema()` right before you do a write, and compare the output?

Comment: Also please update your question with code snippets of how exactly you're reading the files in and writing them out.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your problem is in the `coalesce` directive, when it unifies the data it replaces it and can lead to inconsistencies

Answer (score 0):

1. Pyspark with hive portioned table compaction can be performed using
   the below code .
2. Make sure your mentioning the partition columns

   **table_name = "your_table_name"**

   **partition_columns = ["partition_col1", "partition_col2"]**

   **spark.sql(f"MSCK REPAIR TABLE {DB_name}.{table_name}")**

   **spark.sql(f"ANALYZE TABLE {table_name} COMPUTE STATISTICS")**

Check the statistics of query is completely optional .

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you are saying here,
can you please elaborate maybe with an example?

Comment: Asking follow the above steps during mSCk repair