# processed parquet folder size larger than input folder when transformed with spark

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I m reading parquet files from a folder with spark.

Then, repartition the dataframe(by 3) and then write them again to a target location.
The final folder size in bytes is bigger than the input folder(almost 3 times).

how come ?

**Notes:**

a)input files are parquet, but were inserted into hive table with insertInto. 
 
b)target files are saved with spark.write / same compression snappy

 
c) i noticed that input files has 1 row group in parquet metadata and the target ones have 6 or so
 
d) input files have parquet metadata : hive_schema, the target files have spark_schema

what am I missing ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76618136/directory-size-increased-after-compaction-using-pyspark/76620942#76620942

Comment: As far as (c), you may want to increase `parquet.block.size` to get larger groups. [Parquet doc](https://parquet.apache.org/docs/file-format/configurations/) recommends 1GB.

Comment: Can you share the code ?